# small ticker class to execute a function at a regular inverval

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, timer

I have written the following ticker class. You can find a description and example usage in its comments. However, it kind of feels like I am using too many thread synchronization tools (`std::atomic`, `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`). Is there a way to simplify this?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

// Executes a function f in a fixed interval (given in microseconds).
// Call ticker::start() to run.
// The ticker stops when ticker::stop() is called
// or the instance runs out of scope.
//
// Example usage:
//
// void say_hi()
// {
//     std::cout << "hi " << std::endl;
// }
// int main()
// {
//     ticker hi_ticker( say_hi, 2 * 1000 * 1000 );
//     hi_ticker.start();
//     std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 4500 ) );
// }
class ticker
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void()> function;
    void start()
    {
        if ( running_flag_ )
        {
            return;
        }
        running_flag_ = true;
        thread_ = std::thread( [this]() { thread_function(); } );
    }
    ticker( const function& f, std::int64_t interval_us ) :
        f_( f ),
        interval_us_( interval_us ),
        running_flag_( false ),
        thread_(),
        stop_mutex_(),
        stop_cv_()
    {}
    void stop()
    {
        if ( !running_flag_ )
        {
            return;
        }
        running_flag_ = false;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( stop_mutex_ );
            stop_cv_.notify_all();
        }
        if ( thread_.joinable() )
        {
            thread_.join();
            thread_ = std::thread();
        }
    }
    ~ticker()
    {
        stop();
    }
private:
    void thread_function()
    {
        auto last_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        while ( running_flag_ )
        {
            auto current_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            const auto wake_up_time =
                last_time + std::chrono::microseconds{ interval_us_ };
            while ( current_time < wake_up_time )
            {
                const auto sleep_time = wake_up_time - current_time;
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock( stop_mutex_ );
                stop_cv_.wait_for( lock, sleep_time );
                current_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                if ( !running_flag_ )
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            const auto elapsed = current_time - last_time;
            last_time = current_time;
            const auto elapsed_us =
                std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
                    elapsed).count();
            f_();
        }
    }
    const function f_;
    const std::int64_t interval_us_;
    std::atomic<bool> running_flag_;
    std::thread thread_;
    std::mutex stop_mutex_;
    std::condition_variable stop_cv_;
};
```

edit: Here is the improved version, based on the excellent reviews here: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/99f3b5b0632d57d1f66c94658760c986

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have some doubts about you member variable `running_flag_` and its use in `ticker::start()`. If its purpose is to avoid calling ticker::start() from the same thread then it can be just `bool`, not `std::atomic<bool>`. If its purpose is to avoid calling ticker::start() from the different threads for the same object then you seem to have a data race when two threads might both see running_flag_ equal to false and go ahead with creating **two** threads  later:

```
    if ( running_flag_ )
    {
        return;
    }
    running_flag_ = true;
    thread_ = std::thread( [this]() { thread_function(); } );
```

As far as I know `std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak` must be used in order to avoid such data race when using atomic variable. However as far as I understand you do not expect high contention in ticker::start() and ticker::stop(). So it seems that a more simple approach could be to have running_flag_ as `bool`

```
class ticker {
    // ...
    const function f_;
    const std::int64_t interval_us_;
    bool running_flag_;
    std::thread thread_;
    std::mutex stop_mutex_;
    std::condition_variable stop_cv_;
```

and rewrite functions in this way:

```
void start() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( stop_mutex_ );
    if (running_flag_ )
        return;
    thread_ = std::thread( [this]() { thread_function(); } );
    running_flag_ = true;
}

void stop() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(std::mutex);
    if (!running_flag_)
        return;
    running_flag_ = false;
    lk.unlock(); 
    stop_cv_.notify_one(); // why all? notify_one seems to be enough
    thread_.join();
}
```

Next, why you write explicitly thread_(),stop_mutex_(), stop_cv_()? It is unnecessary.

Then thread_function() seems to be little bit complicated. I have choosen using a predicate in order to stop:

```
void thread_function() {
    auto last_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while ( true ) {
        const auto wake_up_time = last_time + std::chrono::microseconds{ interval_us_ };
        const auto sleep_time = wake_up_time - last_time;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(stop_mutex_);
        if (!running_flag_)
            break;
        stop_cv_.wait_for(lk, sleep_time, [this](){return !running_flag_;});
        if (!running_flag_)
            break;
        lk.unlock();
        last_time = wake_up_time;
        f_();
    }
}
```

And finally. I think you should use std::chrono::steady_clock instead of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock since they cannot be adjusted and according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock:

> This clock is not related to wall clock time (for example, it can be
>   time since last reboot), and is **most suitable for measuring
>   intervals**.

Comment: Sergei, thank you very much for this great review.

I did not think about making the ticker suited to be used from multiple threads yet. Of course there should be a remark in my docs clarifying this.

Your suggestion using `steady_clock` is also very good. I will change my code accordingly.

The unnecessary member initilizations are there, because GCC with `-Werror=effc++` errors otherwise.

Here is the [improved version](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/99f3b5b0632d57d1f66c94658760c986).

Answer (score 3):

- **Clock drift**

  When `thread_function` escapes from the waiting loop, `current_time` most likely is larger than `wake_up_time`. Because of `last_time = current_time;`, the next call will be scheduled later than expected, and the delays will accumulate. To avoid the drift, do `last_time = wake_up_time` instead. You should also define a policy of dealing with extreme delays, e.g. execute outdated calls immediately, or drop them completely.
- Use `std::timed_mutex`.

  Let the main thread lock it, and only unlock it when it wants the ticker to quit. The ticker will [try_lock_for()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/timed_mutex/try_lock_for) it, and quit as soon as the mutex is successfully acquired. No condition_variable, no atomic_flag is necessary anymore.

Comment: vnp, thanks a lot for your well thought out review.

The time drift is a problem I did not yet think about. I will change my code and let it execute outdated calls immediately.

`timed_mutex` is very nice. This makes my code a lot simpler.

Here is the [improved version](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/99f3b5b0632d57d1f66c94658760c986).